# Images defined in CSS are not displayed in a deployed MVC3 site

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a basic MVC3 site and have added image paths into the site.css file (part of the original template).

When I run the application through dev studio the site looks OK and the images are displayed.

When I build my installer and deploy the site onto my server the images aren't displayed.

Here is a sample of my css file:

```
#CustomerLogo
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 96px;
    background-image: url(/Content/themes/base/images/CustomerLogo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: rgb(41,139,178);
}
```

Comment: Does the images exist on the server?

Comment: Yes. The images do exist on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides ensuring that the images are actually loaded on the server, you may want to check whether the application on the server is actually running at the root directory `/`. For example, if your site is located at facebook.com/myGreatApp by prefixing your url with `/` you are telling the browser to look for images at facebook.com/Content/... which is the root rather than at facebook.com/myGreatApp/Content/...

As some other posters have mentioned, the fix for this would be to determine what the actual path from your css to those images is and to use that. A relative path would serve this perfectly and which relative option to use depends on where the css is located in relationship to the images.

Comment: The css is located in the content directory (content\site.css). Should the relative path be from the css file or the page?

Comment: Thanks. I now understand that the path is relative from the CSS file rather than the page file.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like issue with deploying your site to virtual directory. Anyways, you should include images relative to **css file, not to application**. Try

```
background-image: url(themes/base/images/CustomerLogo.jpg);
```

Comment: your suggestion worked. I've marked David as the answer as he started me on the right path. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a relative path? Assuming your css file resides in `~/Content/themes/base`, this should work:

```
background-image: url(images/CustomerLogo.jpg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need a `..` to assist in finding the Content folder,

**Example:**

```
background-image: url(../Content/themes/base/images/CustomerLogo.jpg);
```

Comment: The ".." doesn't seem to work. I think the problem is that using MVC I don't actually know what the path would be to get from the Home\Index.cshtlm view to my image files.

Comment: As David mentioned, another issue may be ensuring that the path for all of your images is relative to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the URL is working? If you try to access the URL directly through the address bar, do you see the image?